# In how many ways can $k$ vertices be inserted somewhere on the $n$ sides of a polygon?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have a polygon of $n$ sides. I would like to insert $k$ vertices somewhere in the $n$ sides. The vertices may be inserted anywhere, in any order, and the order matters.

For example, let us say I have a triangle ABC ($n=3$), and would like to insert $2$ vertices, 1 and 2 ($k=2$) somewhere on the edges of the triangle. Counting the possibilities, A12BC, A21BC, AB12C, AB21C, 1ABC2, 2ABC1, A1B2C, A2B1C, 1AB2C....and so on, I can count $12$. If I had a rectangle ABCD, then I can insert 1 and 2 in $20$ ways (I counted 20 ways). I cannot figure out the mathematical formulation using $n$ and $k$ factorial.

The standard permutation formula does not seem to apply here. For example, in the triangle example, I cannot get to $12$ using $5$, $(3+2)!$, $3!$ and $2!$.

Thinking a bit more, the numerator would be $(n+k-1)!$ given the circular nature. Also if the denominators are $(n-1)!$ and $(k-1)!$, then I end up with the same answer, but I do not know if this is correct, or why?

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation of the examples you gave or a general formula?

Answer (score 1):

If we apply your symbols, the answer is

$$
n(n+1)\cdots (n+k-1)
$$

My understanding is:

for 1st vertex, you have $n$ positions avaiable to place, thus get $n$

for 2nd vertex, you have $n+1$ positions avaiable to place(before 1st, after 1st,others), thus get $n+1$

for 3rd vertex, you have $n+2$ positions avaiable to place(imagine $n+2$ slots formed by previous 2 vertices), thus get $n+2$

and so on.

multiply them, you get $n(n+1)\cdots (n+k-1)$

---

Before asking questions like this, you should look up [Twentyfold_way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#The_twentyfold_way)

It would be better if you know StirlingNumber1, StirlingNumber2, StirlingNumber3, Partitions of a set, Partitions of Integer, Compositions of Integer, Multinomial, Multinomial permutations on a circle, etc.

---

For your question, the answer is

```
Pochhammer[x, n] /. {x -> 2, n -> 2}  (*6,   n=2 objects among x=2 recipients*)
Pochhammer[x, n] /. {x -> 3, n -> 2}  (*12,  n=2 objects among x=3 recipients*)
Pochhammer[x, n] /. {x -> 4, n -> 2}  (*20,  n=2 objects among x=4 recipients*)
```

[image]

Comment: When two vertices are put on the same side, does their position matter?

Comment: @youthdoo In my understanding, when two vertices are put on the same side, their position matter

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your answer, and the pointer for Twentyfold way.